# Save object to useState()

Tags: reactjs

From my back-end I receive data (or an object) that is on the form `{val1: Array(100), val2: Array(100)}`.

If I `console.log` that I get, well, an object in the console containing the above. However, if I try to save that into a `useState` with:

```
const [data, setData] = useState()
```

And try to show/output it in the `return` of my React component, such as:

```
return (
    <div>{data}</div>
)
```

I get the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {val1, val2}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

I was hoping I could just do something like: `{data.val1}` and then I got the data from that and so on. But now I might need to map over everything, or am I doing something wrong here ?

Comment: Try this  `{JSON.stringify(data)}`

Comment: Arh, that seemed to work a bit. But I still can't do `{data.val1}` for instance. But maybe I'm not supposed to be able to do that, or...?

Comment: Is this what you want? https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-roman-3stu7?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Keep in mind that I am using a static data, you will need to set your state with your data from the backend.

Comment: That was the idea yeah. I actually just thought that you could access that data by just doing something like `data.val1` instead of mapping over the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the whole data object in your jsx and as you said you need to use the object keys to access a value like `data.val1`. If the data object is large you can use Object.keys(data) and map the keys on the object.